# "Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer" when adding methods to an ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

I am try to add a dynamic method to ExpandoObject which would return the properties (added dynamically) to it, however it's always giving me error.

Is something wrong I am doing here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace DynamicDemo
{
class ExpandoFun
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fun with Expandos...");
        dynamic student = new ExpandoObject();
        student.FirstName = "John";
        student.LastName = "Doe";
        student.Introduction=new Action(()=>
      Console.WriteLine("Hello my name is {0} {1}",this.FirstName,this.LastName);
    );

        Console.WriteLine(student.FirstName);
        student.Introduction();
    }
}
}
```

The Compiler is flagging the following error:
Error   1

> Keyword 'this' is not valid in a
>   static property, static method, or
>   static field initializer

D:\rnd\GettingStarted\DynamicDemo\ExpandoFun.cs 20  63  DynamicDemo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you're using `this` in the lambda, which would refer to the object that is creating the `Action`. You cannot do that because you're in a static method.

Even if you were in an instance method, it would not work with `this` because it would refer to the instance of the object creating the `Action`, not the `ExpandoObject` where you're tucking it.

You need to reference the ExpandoObject (student):

```
student.Introduction=new Action(()=>
    Console.WriteLine("Hello my name is {0} {1}",student.FirstName,student.LastName);
);
```

Comment: One more question? Then how can I add a factory method to the ExpandObject which would return my a dynamic student?

Comment: @humblecoder: Do you mean this `student.Get = new Func<dynamic>(() => student)`?

Comment: Hi Fernandes!I wanted to create dynamic object (an Active Record) which would have properties (read from the database table columns) and methods (dynamic FindByXXX) where XXX is the column name, similar to NHibernate finders. What's the best approach?

Comment: @humblecoder: I guess that would warrant a whole other question.

Comment: Assume there is a class called student:
    class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
I want to dynamically add the following methods:FindById(),FindByFirstName() and FindByLastName()

like this:
            dynamic student = typeof(Student);
            //dynamic student = new Student();
            student.FindByFirstName = new Action(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I am a lookup method and search the table by FirstName");
            });

Comment: and use in this way:
            dynamic martin = new Student();
            martin.FirstName = "Martinho";
            martin.LastName = "Fernandes";

            martin.FindByFirstName();

Answer (score 3):

There's no "this" available to you.

Capture the object when creating the lambda instead:

`student.Introduction = new Action(
            ()=>
                    Console.WriteLine("Hello my name is {0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName)
            );`

Then it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this` keyword in the action, because here `this` refers to the current instance(not student), which causes the compile error because the code is in a static method. Check this:

```
dynamic student = new ExpandoObject();
student.FirstName = "John";
student.LastName = "Doe";
student.Introduction = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello my name is {0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName));
Console.WriteLine(student.FirstName);
student.Introduction();
student.FirstName = "changed";
Console.WriteLine(student.FirstName);
student.Introduction();
```

Output:

```
John Doe
Hello my name is John Doe
changed Doe
Hello my name is changed Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the action code from the static Main method. There you cannot access object properties. You must replace it with

```
student.Introduction = new Action(
    () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello my name is {0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName);
    };
```

e.g.