# How to Acces a Property of an Usercontrol inside a Thread (Public Static void)

Tags: c#, wpf

How to fix this error:

> Error: Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

Here is the faulty code:

```cs
private void proxietype_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(((Action)delegate
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Check()));
        t.Start();
    }));
}

public static void Check()
{
    ((UserControlVPN)Window.GetWindow(this)).notification.IsActive = true;
    main.notification.IsActive = true;
    main.notification.Message.Content = "Please wait";
}
```

Here as a Picture : [image]

Comment: why do you need `Check()` to be static?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer" when adding methods to an ExpandoObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537141/keyword-this-is-not-valid-in-a-static-property-static-method-or-static-fiel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You don't need a `Dispatcher` to run the `Thread` or `Task` asynchonously

2) Use `Task` instead of `Thread`

3) You may access to instance via static field assigned e.g. in constructor

4) Also you may get an exception while accessing `Window` properties from other than Main UI `Thread`. Here you'll need a `Dispatcher`.

```csharp
private void proxietype_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => Check());
}

// define static field
private static UserControlVPN _thisWindow;

public UserControlVPN()
{
    // assign instance to the field in constructor
    _thisWindow = (UserControlVPN)Window.GetWindow(this);
}

public static void Check()
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)() =>
    {
        _thisWindow.notification.IsActive = true;
        _thisWindow.notification.Message.Content = "Please wait";
    });
    //...
}
```

Or you may just remove `static`. Bacause with this implementation you may have only one instance of the `UserControl` with no problems.

5) Better to use `async/await` approach and modify the Window's properties outside of `Task`.

```csharp
private async void proxietype_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    proxietype.Enabled = false;
    main.notification.IsActive = true;
    main.notification.Message.Content = "Please wait";
    await Task.Run(() => Check());
    main.notification.Message.Content = "";
    main.notification.IsActive = false;
    proxietype.Enabled = true;
}

public static void Check()
{
    // do job...
}
```

Be sure that you have no unhandled exceptions possible inside of `Check()`.